# Bind html to webbrower control?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

i used this method link:http://compiledexperience.com/blog/posts/binding-html-to-the-web-browser-control
but had error message like "HTML not found in the type of webbrowercontrol property". i think it's a simple mistake but I'm new to windows phone.so please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't given much information, but my guess is that you are trying to set a HTML property on the WebBrowser control. The blog post you linked to describes the creation of an attached property, so you need to supply a prefix:

```
<Page xmlns:cxi="clr-namespace: ...">
  <phone:WebBrowser cxi:WebBrowserHelper.Html="{Binding Question.Body}" />
</Page>
```

I would suggest reading about [XAML namspaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086.aspx) and [attached properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: I used that method.but i had error message in NavigateToString(html) like  invalidoperationexecption

Comment: Thank you very much.i made a small mistake.i understand the concept.

Comment: hi ia am struggling to use the webbrowserhelper, wpould you mind explaining to me how to use it? I already made the attached property but how do I trigger the htmlchanged events and display data?